# How to join two rows from a mysql table into a third one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

what I have to do is basiclly create 3 tables.

I have created the first two which are the following.

- table 1

  - User_id
  - email
  - Password
- table 2

  - Schedule_id
  - Time
  - Date
- Table 3 has to be this

  - User_id <<<< that user_id has to be the same as the one mentioned in table number one, where if I was to change the user ID in table 1 it would also change in table number 3
  - number

Comment: what be your question?

Comment: Are you referring to having user_id in table_3 have a foreign key to table_1 on the user_id column? That would cause a foreign key constraint, so that you preserve data integrity. However, you'd also need a process or trigger, that would cascade the change in table_1 to preserve data integrity. All said and done, you should't be changing user_id values, make that a primary/unique key, and have another column that is variable, ie, name.lastname ?

Comment: yes, i want it like that! i wouldnt change user_id values no, ive already set it to a primary key/ unique key ok, so with last name what Would I do? how would i create the table what query? thanks in advance u guys are so helpful god bless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a FOREIGN KEY with a ON UPDATE CASCADE definition, like this:

```
create table table_3 (
  user_id int(10) unsigned,
  CONSTRAINT fk_tb_1_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table_1(user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

int(10) unsigned is a type I invented to exemplify, but it should match exactly the user_id column type in table_1.

But pay attention, for the FOREIGN KEY to work, every user_id in table_3 MUST exist in table_1, you will not be able to insert a user_id in table_3 if it doesn't exist in table_1.